# React help: Main page is not loaded and error message in browser console ("No routes matched location "/")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App font-mono">
      <header className="py-4">
        <Navbar/>
      </header>
      <div>
      <Router>
        <>
        <Routes>
          <Route Path='/' element={<Main />}/>
          <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route Path='*' element={<h1>Wrong Page!</h1>}/>
        </Routes>
        </>
      </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main page is not loaded and browser console shows error message.

`No routes matched location "/"`

What is reason of the error? and solution?

Comment: You've a typos, `Path='/'` should be `path="/"` and `Path='*'` should be `path='*'`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Side note, you may want to also move your `<Navbar />` component *into* the `Router` so any RRD links it renders will work.

Answer (score 1):

Error in line number 12 it should be `path="/"`✅
not `Path="/"` ❌

Comment: Just FYI, typos are a vote-to-close reason since they only help the OP specifically and have no longterm value for future readers.